# QT: итераторы!

Tags: qt, итераторы

Нужна помощь! Как, используя итераторы, найти сумму элементов последовательности, расположенных между первым и последним нулевыми элементами?

```
 #include <Qtcore/QCoreApplication>
 #include <QVector>
 #include <QTextStream>
 #include "iostream"
 #include <QVectorIterator>
 using namespace std;
 int main ()
 {
QCoreApplication a();
QVector <int> vec;

QTextStream stream (stdin), out (stdout);
QString line;

do {
line= stream.readLine();
vec.push_back(line.toInt());
}while (line !=".");
QVectorIterator <int> i(vec);

 do

{
    if (i.hasNext())
          if (i.next == 0){

          }
  else sum=0;

}while(i.peekNext()!=0);
printf ("Sum = %d \n", Sum);
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Откуда взялось требование «используя итераторы»? Если это лаба, вам здесь не рады.

Answer (score 1):

Вот два способа:

1) Используя функционал библиотеки STL (рекомендуемый):

```
 #include <QtСore/QCoreApplication>
 #include <QVector>
 #include <QTextStream>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <numeric> // заголовочный файл численных алгоритмов
 using namespace std;

 int main (int argc, char* argv[])
 {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QVector <int> vec;

    QTextStream stream(stdin), out(stdout);
    QString line;

    do {
       line = stream.readLine();
       bool isOk = false;
       int value = line.toInt(&isOk);
       if (isOk) // обработка ошибки разбора строки в число
           vec.push_back(value);
    }while (line !=".");

    int sum = accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0);
    out << "sum = " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

2) Вручную (ради тренировки):

```
 #include <QtСore/QCoreApplication>
 #include <QVector>
 #include <QTextStream>
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int main (int argc, char* argv[])
 {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QVector <int> vec;

    QTextStream stream(stdin), out(stdout);
    QString line;

    do {
       line = stream.readLine();
       bool isOk = false;
       int value = line.toInt(&isOk);
       if (isOk) // обработка ошибки разбора строки в число
           vec.push_back(value);
    }while (line !=".");

    int sum = 0;
    QVector<int>::iterator it = vec.begin();
    for (; it != vec.end(); ++it)
        sum += *it;
    out << "sum = " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. Писал из головы, работоспособность не проверял.